# How to render individual acronyms in lower case when used inline, but mixed case in the list of acronyms?

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

I would like to output acronyms with the first letter of a word in upper case when they are printed to the list of acronyms. However, it certain cases I would like to print the written out form in lower case (english language) when I add them to a paragraph using the `\ac{}` or `\acf{}` commands. A third case would be to use the mixed letter variant somewhere in the document.

**Examples:**

```
% 1) In the list of acronyms.
Spatial Reference System (SRS)
```

...

```
% 2) In a paragraph.
... the spatial reference system (SRS) is important because ...
```

...

```
% 3) Somewhere else in the document.
... it may happen that you still want to use the 
mixed variant when writing about the Spatial Reference System (SRS) ....
```

**Question:**

- How would you configure acronyms to distiguish between those three cases?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to tell `acronym` both spellings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@in@acrolist
\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{\@in@acrolisttrue}
\newrobustcmd{\LU}[2]{\if@in@acrolist#1\else#2\fi}

\newcommand{\ACF}[1]{{\@in@acrolisttrue\acf{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{SRS}{\LU{S}{s}patial \LU{R}{r}eference \LU{S}{s}ystem}
\acro{DC}{\LU{D}{d}irect \LU{C}{c}urrent}
\end{acronym}

Batteries run on \ac{DC} and \ac{SRS} are different things.
\end{document}
```

The macro `\LU` just takes the alternate forms as its arguments; the `\AtBeginEnvironment` instruction tells this macro that the first argument is to be used, since the conditional `\if@in@acrolist` returns true. In normal text the conditional returns false (note that at the end of the `acronym` environment the setting of the conditional will be automatically reverted, because environments form groups).

[image]

I've added a macro `\ACF` that acts similarly to `\acf` (printing the full version along with the acronym) that uses the uppercase version.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please add some comments to the modifications especially why you included the line: `\expandafter\show\csname if@in@acrolist\endcsname`?

Comment: @JJD Sorry, that line is a relict of my debugging.

Comment: @JJD I've added an `\ACF` macro.