# Acronyms in upper/lower case

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render individual acronyms in lower case when used inline, but mixed case in the list of acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/how-to-render-individual-acronyms-in-lower-case-when-used-inline-but-mixed-case)

I'm using the acronym package.  When I use an acronym in full, I want it to be all lower case; and when used in the acronym list I want the first letter of each word to be capitalised.

For example, in text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, voltage controlled oscillator (VCO), sed do eiusmod tempor...

In acronym list:

> VCO - Voltage Controlled Oscillator

I copied the code fragment from [this issue which is similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list) to give the acronym in lower case in text.  However, it only capitalises the first letter of the first word i.e. VCO - Voltage controlled oscillator.  In addition, some of my acronyms are hyphenated and need capitalisation such as Phase-Locked Loop; and some are hyphenated but do not require capitalisation such as Analog-to-Digital Converter.

Therefore, what I'm thinking is that I should write the acronym definition list how I want it (i.e. capitals, hyphens etc), and then have a code fragment that parses the acro-definitions and makes them words lower case.  But I don't know how to do that or its even possible.

My preamble is:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeindex
```

Note, the acronyms are defined in a separate file that is then included in the frontmatter section:

```
\input{./Frontmatter/acronyms}          % Print the acronyms page
```

And within that, the acronym is simply defined using:

```
\begin{acronym}
\acro{vco}[VCO]{voltage controlled oscillator}
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: I believe that [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/how-to-render-individual-acronyms-in-lower-case-when-used-inline-but-mixed-case) addresses what you want. If it doesn't, please explain why.

Comment: @egreg- I think that solved it!  Thanks for your help!  

(no idea how I didn't the other post, I spent ages searching.  Guess you just have to know which words to use)

Comment: Having answered the question helps. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg- So what now?  How do I mark this question as solved/duplicate/whatever?  :)