# Acronym package: custom list of acronyms which maintains backreferencing

Tags: lists, acronyms, description

I'm using the acronym package for my thesis, and I'd like to create the list of acronyms manually to allow for a more sophisticated formatting, namely upper case in list, lower case in document. I've already tried this alternative solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/how-to-render-individual-acronyms-in-lower-case-when-used-inline-but-mixed-case), but it rendered the commands \Ac, \Acf, etc. (start acronym with capital letter) dysfuntional.

Crucially, I still want acronyms in the text to reference back to the list.

Here´s a first step. Clearly, the backreferencing doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\acrodef{AI}{artificial intelligence}
    
\begin{document}

\section*{List of Acronyms}
How to do this manually, and yet enable backreferencing from text?
\begin{description}
    \item[AI] Artificial Intelligence
\end{description}

\section{Acronym test}
First mention of acronym: \ac{AI}. Second mention of acronym: \ac{AI}.

\end{document}
```

I appreciate any ideas on how to create such a custom list. The documentation has not been very helpful.. https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you moving to the glossaries package as it has the same functionality that you are looking for (and a bit more). You need to include the package as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% Add glossaries
\makeglossaries % <-- This is required to build the glossaries

% 1st param: ID of the acronym
% 2nd param: Actual acronym
% 3rd param: Long version of the acronym
\newacronym{AI}{AI}{artificial intelligence}

\begin{document}
\section{Acronym test}
First mention of acronym: \gls{AI}. Second mention of acronym: \gls{AI}. Forced long version of acronym: \acrlong{AI}.

% Acronym list
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

To compile it run the following commands:

```
 1. pdflatex document
 2. bibtex document
 3. makeglossaries document
 4. pdflatex document
 5. pdflatex document
```

Additionally you could also use `latexmk`

Comment: Thanks Joan, I'm aware of this and the acro package, which should also do a reasonable job. However, the acronym package came integrated with classicthesis and my thesis is already written. Ideally, I'd like to avoid changing the syntax throughout 300 pages of the book.